# Django convert Decimal into integer when point value is 0

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert a Django Decimal field into an integer but only if it has a 0 point value.

So basically:

```
decimal_field = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

Lets say we have the following

```
decimal_field = 15.6
```

Then when I use

```
if int(decimal_field):
  decimal_field = int(decimal_field)
```

It gets converted to 15 instead of staying 15.6
I want this to stay the same and if the decimal is 15.0 to convert to 15

Comment: what do you think `if int(decimal_field)` is doing?

Comment: anyway, I think you want `decimal_field.is_integer()`

Comment: I thought that if int(decimal_field) would check if the decimal could convert to an integer if there were no decimal points. Anyway, your answer is giving an error AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'is_integer'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if decimal_field == int(decimal_field):
    decimal_field = int(decimal_field)
```